Exception in the class destructor
I'm gettin an ImportError exception when execute code:
from requests import Session


class web_client(object):
    def __init__(self, adapter: type):
        self.adapter = adapter
        self.s = Session()
        self.s.verify = False
        self.adapter.auth(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.adapter.close()
        self.s.close()

class adapter(type):

    @classmethod
    def process(cls):
        cls.client.s.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

    @classmethod
    def auth(cls, client: web_client):
        cls.client = client
        cls.process()

    @classmethod
    def close(cls):
        cls.process() # exception here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    web_client(adapter)

Why this code throws an error and how to avoid it?
Exception ignored in: <function web_client.__del__ at 0x00000231EE1D8310>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\main.py", line 12, in __del__
 File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\main.py", line 28, in close
 File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\main.py", line 19, in process
 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 448, in prepare_request
 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 544, in merge_cookies
 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 352, in update
 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\copy.py", line 92, in copy
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down


Please post the full, exact, verbatim error message with traceback.

@deceze added traceback

Well, while the object is in the process of being deleted while Python is shutting down, you trigger adapter.close, which triggers adapter.process, which starts making another get request. That's the problem.

Found this solution:
from requests import Session
from atexit import register


class web_client(object):
    def __init__(self, adapter: type):
        self.s = Session()
        self.s.verify = False
        register(adapter.close) # magic is here
        adapter.auth(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.s.close()
        del self.s


class adapter(type):

    @classmethod
    def process(cls):
        cls.client.s.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

    @classmethod
    def auth(cls, client: web_client):
        cls.client = client
        cls.process()

    @classmethod
    def close(cls):
        cls.process()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    web_client(adapter)


Just don’t call cls.process() from close‽ Why would you start processing on close‽
